# How to get calling app of an Inplicit Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I made a filemanager and I added the **org.openintents.action.PICK_FILE** and **org.openintents.action.PICK_DIRECTORY** actions in the intent-filter inside the manifest, in order to work as FileChooser for other apps. I think these are called *Implicit Intents*. I was thinking in K9 mail client when I did this, since K9 does not come with a file chooser for attachments (!!).

Problem is that K9 crashes if a directory is choosen. So I would like to test how the FileChooser was called, if PICK_FILE or PICK_DIRECTORY.

Where is this info stored?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `getIntent().getAction()` in your activity to get the action string that was used to start your activity originally.

Comment: Excellent, this is what I was looking for. From K9 I get *android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT*, not sure why not PICK_FILE. Thanks!